# Diagonal Victory in Connect 4(C++)

Tags: c++, vector

I am making a connect 4 game in C++. I am making the game so that it is human versus an AI opponent, so for victory parameters it checks if the human has won or if the AI has. I have been able to do this so far for wins that are in rows, and rows that are in columns. The only thing i am having trouble with is detecting four in a row diagonally.

Edit: my board is a 7x6 grid

Here is what i have for checking rows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); ++i)
    {
        if ((board[i][0] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][1] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][2] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][3] == PLAYER_TOKEN) ||
            (board[i][1] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][2] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][3] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][4] == PLAYER_TOKEN) ||
            (board[i][2] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][3] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][4] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][5] == PLAYER_TOKEN) ||
            (board[i][3] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][4] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][5] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[i][6] == PLAYER_TOKEN))
        {
            gameover = true;
            human.setWins(human.getWins()+1);
            cout<<"Congratulations You have Won"<<endl;
            system("PAUSE");
        }
    }
```

And for columns i have this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < board[0].size(); ++j)
{
    if ((board[0][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[1][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[2][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[3][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN) ||
        (board[1][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[2][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[3][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[4][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN) ||
        (board[2][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[3][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[4][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[5][j] == PLAYER_TOKEN))
    {
        gameover = true;
        human.setWins(human.getWins()+1);
        cout<<"Congratulations You have Won"<<endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```

I have been trying to get a similar way to do this for diagonal victories but cannot come up with anything that works. All that i have come to is this which, to be quite frank, does nothing of use!

```
//for (int rows = 0; rows<4; ++rows){
//  for (int columns = 0; columns<3; ++columns){
//      if ((board[rows][columns]     == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+1][columns+1]   == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+2][columns+2]     == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+3][columns+3] == PLAYER_TOKEN) || 
//      (board[rows+1][columns+1] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+2][columns+2] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+3][columns+3] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+1][columns+4] == PLAYER_TOKEN) || 
//      (board[rows+2][columns+2] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+3][columns+3] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+4][columns+4] == PLAYER_TOKEN && board[rows+5][columns+5] == PLAYER_TOKEN))
//      {
//          gameover = true;
//          human.setWins(human.getWins()+1);
//          cout<<"Congratulations you have Won"<<endl;
//          system("PAUSE");
//      }
//  }
//}
```

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to handle each cell separetly and try to check if there is a winner diagonal starting from this cell. Here's a recursive solution

```
bool isWinnerRight(int row, int column, int count) {
  if (row < rows && column < columns && board[row][column] == PLAYERTOKEN) {
    if (count == 4) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return isWinnerRight(row+1.column+1, count+1);
    }
  } else return false;
}

bool isWinnerLeft(int row, int column, int count) {
  if (row < rows && column >= 0 && board[row][column] == PLAYERTOKEN) {
    if (count == 4) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return isWinnerRight(row+1.column-1, count+1);
    }
  } else return false;
}

int main() {
   //do the initialization here
   for (int i = 0; i < rows, i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
       if (isWinnerRight(i,j,0)){/*WINNER FOUND*/}
       if (isWinnerLeft(i,columns-j,0)){/*WINNER FOUND*/}
     }
   }
}
```

Where isWinnerLeft() is analong to isWinnerRight except that in the recursive call

Comment: Sorry i should mention that my grid is 7 x 6, but a win is when 4 tokens are connected in any direction.

Comment: Recursion! Very nice :D Moataz, that is just beautiful! However, is there some risk of the code trying to look outside the range of board?

Comment: yes of course there is such risk, I let out most of the range checks. I will just leave it to you to think what checks could be made :)

Comment: Hi Moataz, i cant seem to get this to trigger a victory when I get a diagonal of 4 in a row.. nothing seems to happen.. Is there anything i could be missing? Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: log messages are your best friend. put them everywhere in the code, give an input example, where there is a winner and observe the behaviour of the program